# Passing a parameter to function with single quote

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I pass a parameter to a javascript function with `'` included

```
var name ="Lauren O'Donald";

var htmlAnch='<a onclick="javascript:selectEmployee(1100,"'+name+'");return false;" 
                 href="javascript:void(0);">O'Donald, Lauren</a>';

 $(document).append($(htmlAnch));
```

The javascript function is not executing since the name `'Lauren O'Donald'` contains single quote.

How can I add a parameter with `'` and prepare dynamic html to make it work?

Here is the dynamic code to generate

```
 var rows = new StringBuffer();

 $(data).each(function(index) {
      rows.append(String.format('<tr><td><a href="No.aspx" 
                onclick="javascript:selectEmployee({3},\"{1} {2}\");return 
               false;">{0}</a></td></tr>',
                String.format("{0}, {1}", this.Surname, this.FirstName),
                this.Surname,
                this.FirstName,
                this.Id
            ));
   });
```

Comment: use a backslash "\" to escape the single quote

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can escape quotes/characters by prepending `\` to it:

```
var string = 'my string with "double quotes" and \'single quotes\'';
var string = "my string with 'single quotes' and \"double quotes\"";
//                                               ^              ^
```

Using a dynamic string:

```
var foo = "bar with 'quotes'";
var string = 'my string with "double quotes" and ' + foo.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
//my string with "double quotes" and bar with \'quotes\'
```

Answer (score 6):

You can escape it using `\`:

```
var htmlAnch='<a onclick="javascript:selectEmployee(1100,\'Lauren O\'Donald\');return false;" 
             href="javascript:void(0);">O\'Donald, Lauren</a>';
```

However as you've tagged this question with jQuery,a better solution is to hook up an event to the element and use `data-*` attributes to store the relevant information, which will avoid the use of ugly `onX` attributes. Try this:

```
var $htmlAnch = $('<a />' {
    text: "O'Donald, Lauren" ,
    data-id: 1100,
    data-name: "Lauren O'Donald"
}).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    selectEmployee($(this).data('id'), $(this).data('name'));
});

$(document).append($htmlAnch);
```

Comment: I updated my code that generates dynamically, and not using data attributes. Please check it

Answer (score 3):

Write your own function to return a escaped string. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ndt9V/)

Pass your string as argument to this function and you will get escaped string. You can also add more characters to blocklist if you want to escape some more characters

```
function remove_quotes(values1)
{
        var values = values1.toString();
        var str = "";
        var blockList = ['"','\'','\\']; // This is the list of key words to be escaped
        var flag = 0;
        for(var i = 0;i<values.length;i++)
        {
            for(var j=0;j<blockList.length;j++)
            {
                if(values[i] == blockList[j])
                {
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag == 0)
            str += values[i];
            else
            {
                str += '\\';
                str += values[i];
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
        return str;

    }
```

Comment: function name suppose to be  escape_quotes

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
    var htmlAnch='<a onclick="javascript:selectEmployee(1100,\'Lauren O\'Donald\');return false;" href="javascript:void(0);">O\'Donald, Lauren</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

In .aspx file you can do like as below:

```
<a data-open="editTemplateOverrideModal" onClick="populateUp
dateModal('<%#Server.HtmlEncode(Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description")).**Replace("'", "\'")) %>')**">
```