# escape java side string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have test.jsp

```
<script>
var name="<%=testName %>";
</script>
```

`"testName"` varible declare globally and it has value `"javascript:alert("hi");"`

while assing value which contains double quotes it is giving unterminated string error. 
I tried it with escape. java side encode/decoding but still have problem of assignment.
what would be way for it in javascript or jquery ??

Comment: just use single quotes inside of it `"javascript:alert('hi');"`

Comment: @DavidFregoli : it's java varibale. it may contain any value. How will you do it at client side means in javascript.

Comment: then escape it in Java, by the time it gets to javascript it's already not parsable

Comment: You can't do it using client script, because you need to escape it before it's parsed, and it's not available to the client script until after it is parsed.

Comment: Maybe use single-quotes as the outer enclosing quotes?  `var name='<%=testName %>';`

Comment: @DavidFregoli : how i can escape it in java side ? by StringEscapeUtil??

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJavaScript(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

You can escape quotes/characters by `prepending \` to it:

in JSP

```
<script>
var name="<%=testName.replace('"','\"') %>";
</script>
```

or in JS

```
alert(variabl.replace(/"/g, '\\"'));
```

check [Passing a parameter to function with single quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399610/passing-a-parameter-to-function-with-single-quote)

Answer (score 0):

try simply

```
<script>
var name=<%=new Gson().toJson(testName)%>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove any quotes from the string on the back-end before passing it to the front-end.

However, if you need to keep quotes in the string, you should escape them on the back-end.

So if the front-end is using single quotes to enclose a string, you'd have to escape single quotes on the backend.

```
String myString = "my string\\'s test";
```

On the front-end, it will end up being

```
var text = 'my string\' test';
```