# Removing mark tags not working with apostrophe (single quote)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a personal program that goes through text and surrounds text with mark tags. It also has a search history footer that you can click on to remove the mark. The marker works fine but the problem occurs when you try to remove the mark tags around a word such as "didn't" (any word with an apostrophe). I'm guessing it has to do with it also being a single quote and it is messing up the function parameters, but I have no idea how to fix it. I have tried messing with the quotes on the function but that doesn't work.

Examples text:

```
<div id="NoteHolder">
    <p class="NoteOp">
        "Testing" <mark class="YelColBox" style="font-weight: bold;">Didn't</mark>
    </p>
</div>
```

A button is on the footer that has the word "Didn't" in it with this function attached:

```
removeMark ('didn't','YelColBox')
```

The function:

```
function removeMark(tagName, Color) {
    var tagNameC = tagName.toUpperCase();
    var IndAry = tags.indexOf(tagNameC);
    tags.splice(IndAry, 1); //removed the word from a search history
    var notes = document.getElementsByClassName("NoteOp");
    for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
      var n = notes[i];
      if(window.Bold === "No") {
         n.innerHTML = n.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("<mark class=" + Color + ">(" + tagName + ")</mark>", "gim"), "$1");
      } 
      if(window.Bold === "Yes") {
         n.innerHTML = n.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("<mark class=" + Color + " style='font-weight: bold;'>('" + tagName + "')</mark>", "gim"), "$1");
      }
      }
    var list = document.getElementById("myList");
    var idmarker = "MarkID" + tagName;
    var ElementID = document.getElementById(idmarker);
    MarkList.removeChild(ElementID); //removes the button
 }
```

What is a solution to my problem. When I click the button, the button isn't removed and I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list    test.html:1
```

Which doesn't make sense because that is  `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Does your button HTML look something like this?:  `<button onclick="removeMark ('didn't','YelColBox')">`

Comment: Your guess is correct. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399610/passing-a-parameter-to-function-with-single-quote

Comment: Yes with an ID of "MarkID" + the word

Comment: You'll need to escape the quote in **didn't**:  `'didn\'t'`.  See @Malk 's link.

Comment: Escape it where? I have escaped it in my marker function.

Comment: Instead of `removeMark ('didn't','YelColBox')`, do `removeMark ('didn\'t','YelColBox')`.

Comment: Ok, then it just removes the button but not the mark tags

Comment: Someone else can debug your function, but you needed to escape the quote to get rid of the syntax error.

Comment: I'm guessing it doesn't remove the mark because it can't find anything with the extra "\". Any suggestions?